# What are the specifications for electrical connectors that can be used for repeated mating in space?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, artificial-satellite, power, docking-port

We’re working on an interface between satellites that when docked has to transmit power and data. The interface needs to have a port for transmitting power and data. Majority of the connectors available online consists of connecting it on earth. What happens to the connectors when exposed to the harsh temperatures while in space? I’m trying to find connectors which can withstand the space environment and function well when it’s plugged.

Comment: different but somewhat related: [Is there a space-certification procedure used by commercial spacecraft manufactures for electronic components?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19310/12102) and links therein. See also [How are electrical connectors on the ISS protected from humidity and contaminants?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35945/12102)  @OrganicMarble yikes! Corrected.

Comment: and while you're at it, don't let this happen to you! [Is it common and good engineering for a pair of cables to be easily plugged into each other's connectors in modern spacecraft?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19310/12102) There's also something called [cold welding](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22cold+welding%22) to worry about...